# Cant remove node_modules file with .staging folder inside

Tags: node.js, windows

I am facing an issue whilst trying to get rid of a folder inside of my node_modules folder. I click delete nothing happens, somethings preventing it from being removed. I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: How long is your overall path? Sometimes this happens when the _total_ path length is over the limit (which I think is ~255 characters).

Comment: Hey Abhishek, my file wasn't too long otherwise the OS would have alerted me. Before posting this question i could move or delete the files, but its now let me for some reason. I just moved the directory to my desktop and deleted it from there, problem solved weirdly :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my linux machine. Managed to delete the node_modules/.staging folder by .... removing my hard drive and deleting it on another pc. No node process was running on either machines. In the 4 years working with node I spent more time trying to fix it.

Comment: Its a very rare and peculiar issue to encounter glad you managed to solve it in the end, even if you did have to remove the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that i found  "I had Antivirus installed on my pc ,which was unknowingly using the files from node_modules folder".

I uninstalled the antivirus or u can change permission setting from antivirus setting option (depends on which antivirus u have).Now i am able to delete  node_modules folder.